# JPA- insert a ID of parent to child table

Tags: jpa

when there is a many to one associate between two object in hibernate(JPA) and we want insert a ID of parent to child table without new record in parent table how do I implement it?

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = RoleEntity.class,cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_ROLE_ID",referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private RoleEntity role;
```

I write this:

```
UserEntity userEntity=new UserEntity();
        userEntity.setUserName(username);
        userEntity.setPassword(password);
        userEntity.setCreatedDate(new Date().toString());
RoleEntity roleEntity=new RoleEntity();
        roleEntity.setTitle("user");
        userEntity.setRole(roleEntity);
```

but the last three line also insert a new record in user table.

This completely of roleEntity:

```
package Entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * Created by Mohsen on 7/10/2018.
 */
@Entity(name = "role")
@Table(name = "ROLE")
public class RoleEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_ROLE", sequenceName = "SEQ_ROLE", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "SEQ_ROLE", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private int id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Title")
    private String title;

//    @OneToMany(targetEntity = UserEntity.class,cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
//    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_ROLE_ID",referencedColumnName = "ID")
//    private Set<UserEntity> user;


    public RoleEntity() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

This completely of userEntity:

```
package Entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by Mohsen on 7/10/2018.
 */
@Entity(name = "user")
@Table(name = "USERR")
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_USER", allocationSize = 1, sequenceName = "SEQ_USER")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "SEQ_USER", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private int id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "UserName", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)")
    private String userName;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Password", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)")
    private String password;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "CreatedDate")
    private String createdDate;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "EndedDate")
    private String endedDate;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = PeopleEntity.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private PeopleEntity people;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = RoleEntity.class,cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_ROLE_ID",referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private RoleEntity role;

    public RoleEntity getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(RoleEntity role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public UserEntity() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(String createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public String getEndedDate() {
        return endedDate;
    }

    public void setEndedDate(String endedDate) {
        this.endedDate = endedDate;
    }

    public PeopleEntity getPeople() {
        return people;
    }

    public void setPeople(PeopleEntity people) {
        this.people = people;
    }

}
```

Comment: excuse me insert new record in role table.

Comment: Can you show RoleEntity and UserEntity completely?

Comment: I have shown it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution

I set cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE in child object and it works